# How to make the value of a cell change when the date is updated?

Tags: excel, vba

In cell "S1" I have the formula that brings today.

I need that when this formula is updated, the value of cell "T3" automatically returns to **0.**

In the codes I tested, it works only if I change the value manually, but I need it to happen automatically.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("S1")) Is Nothing Then
Range("T3").Value = 0
End If

End Sub
```

The code above occurs when I change the date of cell S1 manually, but that's not what I'm looking for, so I know I need to do this in the Worksheet Calculate event, but I don't know the code.

Comment: Have you made an attempt with the `Worksheet_Calculate` event yet?

Comment: I tried but I think I'm doing it wrong, because it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with it?

Comment: How is the date in `S1` changed automatically? Does some other VBA code update it?

Comment: I don't have the code anymore, in addition it slowed down excel

Comment: The date S1 is automatically changed by the function "= Today ()"

Comment: You could use the `Workbook_Open()` event to check if today's date is different to `S1` and then set `T3` to 0. Can that work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need that when it gives 0:00 hours the value of T3 returns to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Worksheet Calculate

- If you would change the value in `S1` manually or by writing via
  `VBA`, then the `Worksheet Change event` should be used.
- If there is a formula in cell `S1`, then you **can** use the
  `Worksheet Calculate event`.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SheetName As String = "Sheet1"
Private Const sCell As String = "S1"
Private Const tCell As String = "T3"
Private Const tValue As Long = 0
Private sValue As Date

Sub populateSrc()
    sValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(sCell).Value
    MsgBox "Today's Date is '" & sValue & "'."
End Sub

Sub checkValue(WorksheetObject As Worksheet)
    On Error GoTo cleanExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If WorksheetObject.Range(sCell).Value <> sValue Then
        WorksheetObject.Range(tCell).Value = tValue
        sValue = WorksheetObject.Range(sCell).Value
    End If
cleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**`ThisWorkbook`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    populateSrc
End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    checkValue Me
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, much better than my other solution, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it another way!

I made this code in the Workbook open so that whenever it opens it takes today's date and puts it in the cell `S2`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open ()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S2").Value = Date

End Sub
```

Another code I made in my macro that makes use of this `T3` cell I put:

```
If Range("S1").Value <> Range("S2").Value Then
Range("T3").Value = 0
Range("S2").Value = Date
End If
```

And solved it! Thank you all for your help!